List editing problem
I have an ill-formed list:
lis = {{"a", "b", "1"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f", "2", "g", "h"}};

I would like to:

Delete from lis all elements that do not contain a digit, and
Delete from the elements of lis any sub-elements that follow a digit

which gives:
res = {{"a","b","1"}, {"e","f", "2"}}

There are no circumstances where two elements are consecutive digits, i.e. no {"e","f","2","3","g","h"}
Thanks for ideas!

You could do it in two steps. First remove the lists inside you do not want (ie. those with no digits), then remove the rest of the list which has digits not at the end.
lis = {{"a", "b", "1"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f", "2", "g", "h"}}
lis = Select[lis, MemberQ[#, _?DigitQ] &]


f[lis_, p_] := If[p < Length[lis], lis[[1 ;; p]], lis]
f[#, First@FirstPosition[#, _?DigitQ, Heads -> False]] & /@ lis


I am sure there are at least 10 other different ways to do this in Mathematica.

lis = {{"a", "b", "1"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f", "2", "g", "h"}};

Using Cases:
Cases[lis, {l__?LetterQ, d_?DigitQ, t___} :> {l, d}]


{{"a", "b", "1"}, {"e", "f", "2"}}

Or using Position, Extract and MapThread:
f[lis_] := MapThread[#1[[;; #2]] &,
           {Extract[lis, List /@ #[[All, 1]]], #[[All, 2]]} &@
           Position[lis, x_String /; DigitQ[x]]]

f@lis


{{"a", "b", "1"}, {"e", "f", "2"}}


Not thoroughly tested, but using Replace with levelspec:
Replace[lis, {{f___, d_?DigitQ, l___} :> {f, d}, {__} :> Nothing}, 2]

Returns:
{{"a", "b", "1"}, {"e", "f", "2"}}


Using Fold, Catch and Throw:
If[AnyTrue[#, DigitQ], 
 Catch[Fold[
  If[DigitQ[#2], Throw[Append[#1, #2], _], 
    Append[#1, #2]] &, {}, #], _, # &], Nothing] & /@ lis

